# what happens if io.redisearch.client.Client.close() is not called in Redisearch?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redisearch

I am using Redisearch through jredisearch api for storing the data in Redisearch Indexes. I access the Redisearch through io.redisearch.client.Client object with the args Client(String indexName, String host, int port, int timeout, int poolSize, String password). I
What happens if the client.close() is not called after querying the Redisearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have a minimum of `0` to a maximum of `poolSize` number of idle socket connections till the rest of the lifetime of your application.